# when I refresh the page that contains a datatable I lose the new data added Primefaces JSF

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf, primefaces, tomcat7

When I refresh the page that contains a datatable I lose the new data added to the datatable I refresh it almost 5 times or I restart the tomcat application server to get the data I posted . im using Primefaces3.4  Hibernate 3 Jsf 2 Tomcat 7.
this is an extract of ManagedBean :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.TimeZone;

import javax.enterprise.inject.New;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.ValueChangeEvent;
import javax.faces.model.SelectItem;

import org.primefaces.event.FlowEvent;
import org.primefaces.event.RowEditEvent;

import com.oxynord.dao.RetourDao;
import com.oxynord.dao.BonbonneDao;
import com.oxynord.dao.BonbonneDataModel;
import com.oxynord.dao.ChargementDao;
import com.oxynord.dao.ChauffeurDao;
import com.oxynord.dao.EnvoiDao;
import com.oxynord.dao.UtilisateurDao;
import com.oxynord.dao.VenteDao;
import com.oxynord.data.*;
public class BonBonneManagedBean {
//test test
//private BonbonneDao BDAO=new BonbonneDao();
private Bonbonne bonbonne=new Bonbonne();
private Bonbonne selectedBonbonne;
private Chauffeur chauffeur=new Chauffeur();
private Chargement chargement=new Chargement();
private Chargement selectedChargement;
private Envoi envoi=new Envoi();
private Envoi selectedEnvoi;
private Client client=new Client();
private Vente vente=new Vente();
private Retour retour=new Retour();
private Client selectedClient;
private List<Client> listClients;
private List<Historiquebonbonne> listhistorique;

// Test Vente
List<Bonbonne> bs=new ArrayList<Bonbonne>();
List<Bonbonne> bs2=new ArrayList<Bonbonne>();

// get user connecté from session
private AuthenticationController authen = (AuthenticationController)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("authenticationController");


private Date date=new Date();

// -- Table à cocher des bonbonnes --
private BonbonneDataModel bonbonneDataModel;
private Bonbonne[] selectedBonbonnes;

boolean next=false;

public boolean isNext() {
    return next;
}

public void setNext(boolean next) {
    this.next = next;
}


// -------------------------------- edit -----------------------------------------------

// modifier une bonbonne
public void onEdit(RowEditEvent event) throws Exception {  
        BonbonneDao.ModifierBonbonne(((Bonbonne) event.getObject()));   
} 
// modifier un chauffeur
public void onEditChauffeur(RowEditEvent event) throws Exception {  
    BonbonneDao.ModifierChauffeur(((Chauffeur) event.getObject())); 
 }
```

and this is BonbonneDAO :

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
     import java.util.Date;
     import java.util.List;

     import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
     import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

     import org.hibernate.Session;

     import com.oxynord.data.Bonbonne;
     import com.oxynord.data.Chauffeur;
     import com.oxynord.data.Client;
     import com.oxynord.data.Domaine;
     import com.oxynord.data.Etatactuelle;
     import com.oxynord.data.Historiquebonbonne;
     import com.oxynord.data.Produit;
     import com.oxynord.data.Stock;
     import com.oxynord.data.Utilisateur;
     import com.oxynord.data.Ville;
     import com.oxynord.data.Volume;
     import com.oxynord.utile.HibernateUtil;

     public class BonbonneDao {
Date date=new Date();

//----------List Historiquebonbonne--------------------------

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static List<Historiquebonbonne> HistoriqueBonbonne(Bonbonne bonbonne) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        List<Historiquebonbonne> listHistoriquebonbonne= new ArrayList<Historiquebonbonne>();
        listHistoriquebonbonne= session.createQuery("from Historiquebonbonne as h where h.bonbonne.idBonbonne='"+bonbonne.getIdBonbonne()+"' order by h.idHistorique desc ").list();
        return listHistoriquebonbonne;
    }

//----------List des bonbonnes qui ont dépasser la date de 3 mois--------------------------

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static List<Bonbonne> BonbonnesVendu() {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    List<Bonbonne> listBonbonnesVente= new ArrayList<Bonbonne>();
    listBonbonnesVente = session.createQuery("from Etatactuelle where libelle= 'Vendu' ").list();
    return listBonbonnesVente;
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static List<Bonbonne> ListBonbonnesVide() {
    try {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    List<Bonbonne> listBonbonnes= new ArrayList<Bonbonne>();
    listBonbonnes = session.createQuery("from Bonbonne where etatactuelle.idEtat=1 and stock.idStock=1").list();
    return listBonbonnes;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return null;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static  List<Bonbonne> AllBonbonnes() {
    try {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    List<Bonbonne> listBonbonnes= new ArrayList<Bonbonne>();
    listBonbonnes = session.createQuery("from Bonbonne").list();
    return listBonbonnes;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return null;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static List<Produit> AllProduits() {
    try {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    List<Produit> listProduit= new ArrayList<Produit>();
    listProduit = session.createQuery("from Produit").list();
    return listProduit;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return null;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static List<Ville> AllVille() {
    try {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    List<Ville> listVille= new ArrayList<Ville>();
    listVille = session.createQuery("from Ville").list();
    return listVille;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return null;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static List<Domaine> AllDomaine() {
    try {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    List<Domaine> listDomaine= new ArrayList<Domaine>();
    listDomaine = session.createQuery("from Domaine").list();
    return listDomaine;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return null;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static List<Volume> AllVolumes() {
    try {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    List<Volume> listVolume= new ArrayList<Volume>();
    listVolume = session.createQuery("from Volume").list();
    return listVolume;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return null;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static List<Etatactuelle> AllEtatsActuelleBonbonne() {
    try {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    List<Etatactuelle> listEtatactuelle= new ArrayList<Etatactuelle>();
    listEtatactuelle = session.createQuery("from Etatactuelle").list();
    return listEtatactuelle;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return null;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static List<Stock> AllStocks() {
    try {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    List<Stock> listStock= new ArrayList<Stock>();
    listStock = session.createQuery("from Stock").list();
    return listStock;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return null;
}

// ---------------------------- Ajouter Bonbonne -----------------------------------------------

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static boolean addBonbonne(Bonbonne bonbonne) throws Exception {
    try {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    org.hibernate.Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    List<Bonbonne> b=session.createQuery("from Bonbonne where codebare='"+bonbonne.getCodebare()+"' or numeroSerie='"+bonbonne.getNumeroSerie()+"'").list();

    /* Test si le bonbonne est deja enregistrer
     si oui --> afficher que le bobonne est deja enregistrer
     si non --> enregistrer le bonbonne */

    if(b.size()==0) {
    //Utilisateur u=(Utilisateur) session.createQuery("from Utilisateur").list().get(0);    
    //bonbonne.setUtilisateur(u);
    session.save(bonbonne); 
    tx.commit();
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("une bonbonne a été enregister avec succes"));
    return true;
    } else {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN,"Il existe déjà un Code barre:"+b.get(0).getCodebare()+" avec un numero de série:"+b.get(0).getNumeroSerie()+"", "Code barre ou numero de série déjà enregistrer"));  
    return false;
    }

    } catch (Exception e) {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,"Erreur d'enregistrement", "Erreur d'enregistrement"));  
    System.out.println(e);
    return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Post some code first, how can we know where is the problem?But from what you have written - is your ManagedBean ViewScoped?

Comment: So make it ViewScoped;-)

Comment: it works but I'll see if it will not cause me problems in the development . Thank you

Comment: it worked at first but I have the same problem again even if I put my Managedbean ViewScoped :(

Comment: Still have to restart the application server to get the data I posted :(

Answer (score 1):

Change your managed bean's scope to: @javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped

Comment: still have the same problem  even if I put the Managedbean ViewScoped

Answer (score 0):

You should use `@ViewScoped` to make sure the data will persist as long as you stay in the same view (aka yourpage.xhtml).

If you perform operations in the same page, make sure your methods are type `void` or return null otherwise. This will keep you in the same view.

Perform a `flush` right after persisting in your DAO layer.

This is a guess based on the behavior you are describing. If it works you should adjust your Hibernate layer flush/commit options as it seems the items are being persisted but not committed/flushed and then not updating the persistence context thus not showing in the page afterwards.

I hope it helps.

Comment: when I add data  they are in the database so it's persisted commited and posted on my page but when I refresh my page I lose it when I update several times they appear again

Comment: @Bob How do you load data? Please, post some more code. Bean construction and data listing.